# Cosa sono gli "stracciari"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Cosimo ogni notizia nuova andava a commentarla coi calderai. Tra la gente accampata nel bosco, c'era a quei tempi tutta una genìa di loschi ambulanti: calderai, impagliatori di seggiole,  **stracciari**, gente che gira le case, e al mattino studia il furto che farà alla sera. Nel bosco, più che il laboratorio avevano il rifugio segreto, il ripostiglio della refurtiva.

Qualcuno di voi sa spiegare cosa sono questi "stracciari"? Nei dizionari che ho consultato, non ho trovato né "stracciario", né "stracciaro" e il termine "stracciare" appare solo come verbo.

Comment: In dialetto veneto, *strassaro* (la doppia s indica solo la pronuncia sorda); *strassa* (femminile) è lo straccio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo **stacciaro** o [stracciaiolo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stracciaiolo1/) è

> Chi compra e rivende stracci e altra roba usata di poco valore,
>   straccivendolo: *bottega di s.; s. ambulante; una vecchietta, che
>   teneva bottega da stracciarola sotto la loggia* (Bacchelli).

Puoi trovare anche alcune varianti regionali di [stracciaiolo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stracciaiolo_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/):

> stracciaiolo /stratʃ:a'jɔlo/ (lett. stracciaiuolo, region.
>   stracciarolo) s. m. [der. di *straccio*²] (f. -a). - (*mest*.) [chi compra
>   e rivende stracci e altra roba usata di poco valore] ≈ (*tosc.*)
>   cenciaio, (*tosc*.) cenciaiolo, straccivendolo. ⇑ rigattiere,
>   robivecchi.

Comment: La risposta suona sensata, ma al di là del buon senso hai qualche fonte, o qualche altro testo in cui compare "stracciaro"?